# Unclear syntax error with use statement in function

Tags: php, syntax, namespaces

I try to implement a web app with DropBox API...

In this part of the code:

[...]

```
require_once "dropbox/lib/Dropbox/autoload.php"; 
use \Dropbox as dbx;    
$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile("app_info.json");
```

[...]

I get a syntax error in the second line: "syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)"
I copy this code from other place in my project... and it work there... I can't understant whats happening here!
I already try everything, every combination but i can't see the problem!

Comment: Did you try it without the backward slash on the second line?

Comment: I think it's related to which version of PHP you use. Namespace where introduced in PHP 5.3.0. What is your PHP version ?

Comment: @Mathlight he's getting a syntax error. not a "Class not Found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the syntax error it looks like you're trying to `use` within a function declaration (or possibly within a class definition, though the error may be different there depending whether or not your PHP version supports traits.)

Per the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php):

> The *use* keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK use statements must go first:

```
use \Dropbox as dbx;        

require_once "dropbox/lib/Dropbox/autoload.php"; 

$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile("app_info.json");
```

Comment: I think, @derp is right. In most common cases it actually is first but NTL because its just below the namespace declaration ...